# Percent on basis of row count and row count on basis of condition in single table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have four tables with the following structure.

```
Table 1:
Project - have unique project names (prj_name)

Table 2:
my_records - have the following fields:
record_id,prj_name,my_dept,record_submit_date,record_state

Table 3:
record_states have multiple states where 'Completed' is one.

Table 4:custom_dept_list
dept_name
```

I need to get the percentage of (records have state as completed) and (Total records) grouped by my_project where my_dept in custom_dept_list and record_submit_date is greater than "some date"

I have tried the following:

```
Query:
    select prj_name,count(record_id) as total,((select count(record_id) from  
my_records where record_state='Completed')/(count(record_id)))*100 as 
percent  from my_records,custom_dept_list where record_state='Completed' 
and   record_submit_date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY ) and  
my_dept=dept_name group by prj_name order by percent desc; 

Total records for project A = 50
Total records for project A with record_state='Completed' = 30
Ratio is not coming - (30/50)*100 = 60
It is giving some very big value.
```

Below is the data from `my_records`, i have removed record_submit date to make it simple:

```
|1|prj1|dept1|Completed
|2|prj1|dept1|XYZ
|3|prj1|dept1|Completed
|4|prj1|dept2|XYZ
|5|prj1|dept2|Completed
|6|prj1|dept1|XYZ
|7|prj1|dept1|XYZ
|8|prj1|dept1|XYZ
|9|prj1|dept2|XYZ
|10|prj1|dept2|XYZ
|11|prj1|dept2|Completed
|12|prj1|dept2|Completed
|13|prj1|dept2|Completed
|14|prj1|dept3|XYZ
|15|prj1|dept4|Completed
|16|prj1|dept4|XYZ
|17|prj1|dept5|Completed
|18|prj1|dept6|XYZ
|19|prj1|dept7|XYZ
|20|prj1|dept8|XYZ
|21|prj1|dept10|XYZ
|22|prj1|dept2|XYZ
|23|prj1|dept2|Completed
|24|prj1|dept2|Completed
|25|prj1|dept2|Completed
```

Data From `Custom_dept_List`:

```
dept_name
dept1
dept3
dept4
dept5
dept6
dept8
dept10
```

I have tried the following queries :

Query 1

```
select count(record_id) as count,prj_name from my_records,custom_dept_list where my_dept=dept_name group by prj_name order by count desc;

Ouput -- 13
```

Query 2

```
select count(record_id) as count,prj_name from my_records,custom_dept_list where my_dept=dept_name and record_state='Completed' group by prj_name order by count desc;

Output -- 4
```

Query 3

```
select  prj_name,count(record_id) as total,count(case when record_state='Completed' then record_id end) /count(record_id) *100 as percent from my_records join custom_dept_list on my_dept = dept_name where   record_state = 'Completed' group by prj_name order by percent desc;
```

Output :

```
prj_name total percent
prj1       4    100.0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need this `record_state = 'Completed'` condition because of this you get only completed record as total recoded. so try without it.

```
select  prj_name,
        count(record_id) as total,
        count(case when record_state='Completed' then record_id end) /
        count(record_id) * 100 as percent
from    my_records
join    custom_dept_list
on      my_dept = dept_name
where   record_submit_date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY )
group by prj_name
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please use proper `join` instead of multiple tables in your `from` clause.

Then, you don't need that inner query to get the count with a specific `record_state`, you can use a `case` inside the `count`:

```
select  prj_name,
        count(record_id) as total,
        count(case when record_state='Completed' then record_id end) /
        count(record_id) * 100 as percent
from    my_records
join    custom_dept_list
on      my_dept = dept_name
where   record_submit_date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY )
group by prj_name
order by percent desc;
```

Your problem was probably caused by that inner query, that was not counting each project's completed records, but all the completed records instead.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but after removing an extra "and" in where  , It is giving 100 percent for all prj_name.

Comment: Fixed the typo... can you please edit your question with some sample data from those two tables?

Comment: I have edited question with sample data , just removed record_submit_date for making it simple to build rough data..